# SPI Data write/read

Tags: memory, sd-card, spi

I use the below command to pass data from SPI Core to Flash Memory or SD Card etc.

```
XSpi_Transfer(&Spi, SendData, ResData, 1);
```

I understand that in order to save\read data on memory we need to give an address.

But what I don't understand is how do I specify address in above command.

Answer (score 0):

This [github page](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/spi/examples/xspi_atmel_flash_example.c) shows an example function named [`SpiAtmelFlashRead`](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/spi/examples/xspi_atmel_flash_example.c#L367) with the following syntax:

```
SPI_Status = SpiAtmelFlashRead(&spi, Address, ByteCount);
```

The code inside the read function is:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function reads data from the Atmel Flash device connected to the SPI
* interface.
*
* @param    SpiPtr is a pointer to the SPI driver component to use.
* @param    Addr is the address from which the data is to be read from
*       the Flash.
* @param    ByteCount is the number of bytes to read.
*
* @return   XST_SUCCESS if successful else XST_FAILURE.
*
* @note     None.
*
******************************************************************************/
int SpiAtmelFlashRead(XSpi *SpiPtr, u32 Address, u16 ByteCount)
{
    u16 Index;

    /*
     * Setup the read command with the specified address and data for the
     * Atmel Flash.
     */
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_COMMAND_OFFSET]   = ATMEL_COMMAND_READ;
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE1_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 16);
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE2_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 8);
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE3_OFFSET] = (u8) Address;

    /*
     * Prepare the write buffer. Fill in some dummy data.
     */
    for(Index = 4; Index < (ByteCount + ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES);
                Index++) {
        WriteBuffer[Index] = ATMEL_DUMMYBYTE;
    }

    /*
     * Prepare the Read Buffer. Fill in some initialization data into the
     * the buffer.
     */
    for(Index = 0; Index < (ByteCount +
                ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES); Index++) {
        ReadBuffer[Index] = ATMEL_INITBYTE;
    }

    /*
     * Send the read command to the Atmel Flash to read the specified number
     * of bytes.
     */
    TransferInProgress = TRUE;
    XSpi_Transfer(SpiPtr, WriteBuffer, ReadBuffer,
                ByteCount + ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES);

    /*
     * Wait till the Transfer is complete and check if there are any errors
     * in the transaction.
     */
    while (TransferInProgress);
    if(ErrorCount != 0) {
        ErrorCount = 0;
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

This [github page](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/spi/examples/xspi_atmel_flash_example.c) shows an example function named [`SpiAtmelFlashWrite`](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/spi/examples/xspi_atmel_flash_example.c#L432) with the following syntax:

```
SPI_Status = SpiAtmelFlashWrite(&spi, Address, chunk, ByteCount);
```

The code inside the write function is:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/**
*
* This function writes to the Atmel Flash device connected to the SPI interface.
*
* @param    SpiPtr is a pointer to the SPI driver component to use.
* @param    Address is the address to which the data is written.
* @param    ByteCount contains the number of bytes to write.
*
* @return   XST_SUCCESS if successful else XST_FAILURE.
*
* @note     None.
*
******************************************************************************/
int SpiAtmelFlashWrite(XSpi *SpiPtr, u32 Address, u16 ByteCount)
{
    u16 Index;

    /*
     * Setup the write command with the specified address, and data to be
     * written to the flash.
     */
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_COMMAND_OFFSET]     = ATMEL_COMMAND_WRITE;
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE1_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 16);
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE2_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 8);
    WriteBuffer[ATMEL_ADDRESS_BYTE3_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address);

    /*
     * Prepare the write buffer. Fill in the data that is to be written into
     * the Flash.
     */
    for(Index = 4; Index < (ByteCount + ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES);
            Index++) {
        WriteBuffer[Index] = (u8)(ATMEL_TEST_BYTE + Index);
    }

    /*
     * Send the write command, address, and data to the Flash.
     * No receive buffer is specified since there is nothing to receive.
     */
    TransferInProgress = TRUE;
    XSpi_Transfer(SpiPtr, WriteBuffer, NULL,
            ByteCount + ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES)
                            ;

    /*
     * Wait till the Transfer is complete and check if there are any errors
     * in the transaction.
     */
    while (TransferInProgress);
    if(ErrorCount != 0) {
        ErrorCount = 0;
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: As explained in Atmel Flash example:                                       XSpi_Transfer(SpiPtr, WriteBuffer, NULL,
            ByteCount + ATMEL_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES);                 what I don't understand is that (in the above XSpi_transfer function example), If the WriteBuffer contains address (as evident) then the Data is stored in which variable.

Answer (score 0):

The actual protocol for communicating with your external memory device will be specified in its datasheet (i.e. the way you send an address and commands to the chip will be different between manufacturers and product lines).  It looks like your function simply initiates a single SPI transfer.  You will most likely have to call the function several times to send a specific sequence of bytes/words that collectively make up a write command, address, and data.  Again, this all depends on the datasheet.  It would also be helpful to see what exactly is going on in `XSpi_Transfer`.

Also remember to make sure the SPI polarity, phase, and data bits are set correctly in your SPI configuration routine.